# Using geo location Google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, supportmapfragment

I have added a map fragment to my app including a geographic marker and included my play services jar but I'm getting the following error on my marker code:

```
Error: Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment
```

The snippet is as follows:

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(53.271900177, -9.04889965057))
                .title("GMI alway Location"));;
```

This is my xml declaration to reference it:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Anyone have any ideas as to where I'm going wrong? Thanks Brian J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `SupportFragmentManager` and the `FragmentActivity` classes if you are using the `SupportMapFragment` in your layout.

So use the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I tried the above fix but I get this error:  'The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MapGmit'

Comment: your Activity extends FramgnetActivity?

Comment: what class MapGmit extends?

Comment: MapGmit extends MapActivity which is the xaml file for the map fragment activity.

Comment: MapGmit should extend FramgnetActivity.